# TYPO3: Does "inject" imply "require"?

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3, require

In my TYPO3 Extbase extension I widely use services of other extensions. All variables, providing such external sevices, are filled through injection.

The question is: what happens, if the target extension (or service file) isn't there? My variable has value `NULL` and PHP throws exception *function call on a non-object*.
Isn't it better to secure such files, using external functionality, with `require_once` directives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to ensure the installation of other extensions would be to mark them as "required" in your `ext_emconf.php` (and maybe in your `composer.json` as well, not sure).

This would ensure that required *extensions* are there - but not that the required services still exist in those extensions. They could be removed or renamed in later versions. To circumvent that, you could either require a specific version of the extension, or you could try to only use their public API.